# sed command to edit stream on given rule

Tags: shell, sed, awk, tr

I have an input stream like this:

```
afs=1;bgd=1;cgd=1;djh=1;fgjhh=1;
```

Now the rule I have to edit the stream is:
(1)if we have

```
"djh=number;"
```

replace it with

```
"djh=number,"
```

(2)else replace "string=number;"it with

```
"string,"
```

I can handle case 2 as:

```
sed 's/afs=1/afs,/g;s/dbg=1/dbg,/g;..... so on for rest
```

How to take care for condition 1?

The "djh" number can be any number(1,12,100), the other numbers are always 1.

all the double quotes I have used are for reference only; no double quotes are present in the input stream. "afs" can be "Afs" also. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/;/,/g; s/,djh=/,@=/; s/\([a-z][a-z]*\)=[0-9]*,/\1,/g; s/@/djh/g'
```

This does the following

1. replace all `;` by `,`
2. replace `djh` with `@`
3. remove `=number` from all lower cased strings
4. replace `@` with `djh`

This results in `afs,bgd,cgd,djh=1,fgjhh,` for your input. Of course you could substitute djh with any other character that makes it easy to match the other strings. This is just illustrating the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and also explaining it nicely but other string can have capital letters .. I will update my question .. thanks

Comment: Okay, then I'll use the `@` character.

Comment: thanks a lot this works fine for me and greater than that i actually learned something .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "afs=1;bgd=1;cgd=1;djh=1;fgjhh=1;" |
sed 's/^/\n/;:a;/\n\(djh=[0-9]*\);/s//\1,\n/;ta;s/\n\([^=]*\)=1;/\1,\n/;ta;s/.$//'
afs,bgd,cgd,djh=1,fgjhh,
```

Explanation:

This method uses a unique marker (`\n` is a good choice because it cannot appear in the pattern space as it is used by sed as the line delimiter) as anchor for comparing throughout the input string. It is slow but can scale if more than one exception is needed.

- Place the marker in front of the string `s/^/\n/`
- Name a loop label `:a`
- Match the exception(s) `/\n\(djh=[0-9]*\)/`
- If the exception occurs substitute as necessary. Also *bump* the marker along  `/s//\1,\n/`
- If the above is true break to loop label `ta`
- Match the normal and substitute. Also *bump* the marker along `s/\n\([^=]*\)=1;/\1,\n/`
- If the above is true break to loop label `ta`
- All done remove the marker `s/.$//`

or:

```
echo "afs=1;bgd=1;cgd=1;djh=1;fgjhh=1;" | 
sed 's/\<djh=/\n/g;s/=[^;]*;/,/g;s/\n\([^;]*\);/djh=\1,/g'
afs,bgd,cgd,djh=1,fgjhh,
```

Explanation:

This is fast but does not scale for multiple exceptions:

- Globaly replace the exception string with a new line `s/\<djh=/\n/g`
- Globaly replace the normal condition `s/=[^;]*;/,/g`
- Globaly replace the `\n` by the exception string `s/\n\([^;]*\);/djh=\1,/g`

N.B. When replacing the exception string make sure that it begins on a word boundary `\<`

Comment: can you please explain it how it is achieving the task .. i am new to shell scripting and this one is difficult to understand for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'afs=1;bgd=1;cgd=1;djh=1;fgjhh=1;' | 
sed -e 's/\(djh=[0-9]\+\);/\1,/g' -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)=1;/\1,/g'
```

Comment: can you please explain it how it is achieving the task .. i am new to shell scripting and this one is difficult to understand for me :)

Comment: @Jens: Support for `\+` (equivalent to `..*`) varies by version of `sed`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson If it does that (which sed, GNU?), then the solution makes unstated assumptions. As per POSIX `\+` is undefined. I strongly recommend avoiding it, since it only saves one character of typing. If it really were `..*` it still would not work because it requires at least one character, but in `djh=1;` the 1 is matched by `[0-9]` and no character left.

Comment: @Jens: I was speaking in the general case when I said `..*`. In the specific case, it would be `[0-9][0-9]*` vs. `[0-9]\+` (saving 4 characters). The latter works in GNU `sed` and some others.